# Family of Cauchy sequences in metric space - question regards notation

Tags: general-topology, notation, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

I'm attempting to learn about the construction of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ by completion of the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. The notes I am following do this by defining the set of real numbers as cosets of Cauchy sequences. However, when proving this set to be complete I ran into some notation that I had not seen before. Here is some introduction to where I am:

Let $Y$ be the cosets, as mentioned, and let $d$ be a metric hereon. I wish to prove that the metric space $(Y,d)$ is complete. To this end, my notes define a family of Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ as:

$(x_n^{(k)})$, k=1,2,3,...

And a Cauchy sequence in Y:

$\lbrace [(x_n^{(k)})]\rbrace_{k=0}^{\infty}$

I have trouble decoding what is meant by these two notations; that is, I am not sure how to visualize (or even understand) what is meant by the definitions. As a bonus I would like to ask what a 'family' is in this context. 
Thank you very much,

kasp9201

Comment: "Family" is merely a poor choice of words. Probably the writer is trying to avoid the phrase "sequence of Cauchy sequences," but that is what the writer means. $\{x_1^{(i)},x_2^{(i)},\dots\}$ is the $i$th Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Ah, neat. With this answer I was able to figure out the rest. If you want to post this as a formal answer I will accept it and add to it (if possible) what I learned. Otherwise I will just post an answer myself